# How to convert datatable into generic type

Tags: c#, linq, generics, list

How to convert DataTable having N rows into `KeyValuePair<long,string>[]` type having same N no of rows

I want to return `KeyValuePair<long,string>[]` kind of value from a function that will convert DataTable into above type.

Comment: Do you only have to fields with datatype long and string in the datatable?

Comment: @Yves: I will be checking Datatype before processing further as i need it to be done for this datatype only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new KeyValuePair<long, string>(r.Field<long>("longFieldName"), r.Field<string>("stringFieldName")))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: You mean .ToArray() - and it's worth mentioning that the long column may not be null.

Comment: Thanks, I got ahead of myself there.  D'oh.